# Как сделать заполнение PregressBar градиентным

Tags: java, android, drawable

У меня есть `drawable` которую я использую в качестве `background` в `ProgressBar`, т.е. мне нужно что бы фон был  серый а строка заполнения градиентом. Идеально было  бы если бы градиент был не просто  от светлого к темному, а светлый -> темный  -> светлый  -> темный, ну т.е. что  бы градиенты чередовались. Как такое можно реализовать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBackgroundGrey" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <solid android:color="#E0CFBA" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Картинка для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#88cacacf" android:centerColor="#88f8f8fd" android:endColor="#88cacacf"/>
</shape>
```

Цвета укажите свои собственные.